# Running Deployment project gives me "Something" is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, deployment, aspnet-compiler

I have a deployment project for web application 
when I run the deployment project it gives me this error 
Error   443 'http:/localhost:54333/Content/XXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.ascx' is not a valid virtual path.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot navigate to a .ASCX file. The .ASCX file is a user control, it's not a .ASPX web form.

Comment: I'm not navigating the website I'm Just deploying it

Comment: vs was generating wrong code while adding user control to another one . it adds the line which make the error : http:/localhost:54333/Content/XXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX.ascx

Comment: I caused this situation once by accidentally consuming a control from a different assembly: I had 2 web applications in the same solution with identical ascx controls (both sets inheriting from a common base class of course). Dragging the control from the other assembly added the localhost reference... fixed it by changing "http://localhost:99999" to "~", which causes the local control to be referenced (assuming the local path is the same).

Answer (score 0):

ascx is used for user type controls ,its not denoting any page like .aspx does ,so you cant navigate to ascx